# Take the header of most-left value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, headers, lookup

I'm using the formula from this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1415472/how-to-get-right-most-value-of-row-in-excel#new-answer?newreg=544c214afefb4c2f801f594c7d6395ad) to take the most left value from my excel sheet.

I’m using this formula for column “N” as shown at this [excel print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Im6c.png).
Now I have to find the most left value, and get the header (date when it occurred), and place this number at column “O”.

[image]

Comment: Please post the formula that returns the number

Answer (score 0):

If you try to lookup an impossibly large number with an approximate MATCH then you get the position of the last (right-most) number in a row. Try this in O2.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(R$1:AC$1, MATCH(1E+99, R2:AC2)), "")
```

To find the first (left-most), change to AGGREGATE finding the position for INDEX.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(R$1:AC$1, , AGGREGATE(15, 7, COLUMN(A:L)/(R2:AC2>0), 1)), "")
```

Drag down for subsequent rows.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! 
Actually I'm already finding the most-left value (column N). 
Now, I want to know when this value occurred (date on header).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you even try the second formula?